# Make journalctl keep all logs forever (SystemMaxUse = unlimited)

Tags: linux, logging, systemd, journald, journalctl

How do I configure journald so that it never, ever, ever deletes my logs.

Yes, what I want to do is tell journald to keep writing until the disk (read: `/var` partition's filesystem) is full.

No, I don't want it to keep storing to memory until the RAM is full.

According to `man 5 journald.conf`,

```
SystemMaxUse=, SystemKeepFree=, SystemMaxFileSize=, SystemMaxFiles=,
RuntimeMaxUse=, RuntimeKeepFree=, RuntimeMaxFileSize=, RuntimeMaxFiles=
    Enforce size limits on the journal files stored. The options
    prefixed with "System" apply to the journal files when stored on a
    persistent file system
...
    The first pair defaults to 10% and the second to 15% of the size of
    the respective file system, but each value is capped to 4G.
```

So the default is some percent of the filesystem with a cap at 4G. Unfortunately, I don't see any mention of how to set it to unlimited in the above man page.

How do I make `journald` never delete my logs? Bonus points for additional options that increase rotation & compression, etc.

Comment: The expectation here is that if you need longer persistence that you will be shipping the logs elsewhere, whether that be a central ELK stack, Splunk, or just a local rsyslog.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418460/how-to-make-journald-increase-logs-storage-capacity